# How to charge users by usage?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I’m building a service and I’m planning to charge a fixed price for each lambda call.

How to count requests per client if the lambda function being called is the same? I’m planning to pass a client id

Answer (score 2):

You can use API Gateway Usage Plans for your requirement.

After you create, test, and deploy your APIs, you can use API Gateway usage plans to make them available as product offerings for your customers. You can configure usage plans and API keys to allow customers to access selected APIs at agreed-upon request rates and quotas that meet their business requirements and budget constraints. If desired, you can set default method-level throttling limits for an API or set throttling limits for individual API methods.

A *usage plan* specifies who can access one or more deployed API stages and methods—and also how much and how fast they can access them. The plan uses API keys to identify API clients and meters access to the associated API stages for each key. It also lets you configure throttling limits and quota limits that are enforced on individual client API keys.

Read [this docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-api-usage-plans.html) for more detail explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use api gateway https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/

"Amazon API Gateway is a fully managed service that makes it easy for developers to create, publish, maintain, monitor, and secure APIs at any scale. APIs act as the "front door" for applications to access data, business logic, or functionality from your backend services."

It provides you with statistics about usage as well as different options like limit numbers of requests per api_key, etc